# I want to shuffle the data after getting this data from firestore in flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

I am getting the data from **firestore** like

```
 Future userDoc;

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    userDoc=getPosts();
  }

Future getPosts() async {
    var firestore=Firestore.instance;
    QuerySnapshot qn=await firestore.collection('documents').getDocuments();
    return qn.documents;
  }
```

So now i want to **shuffle** this **userDoc** but its not working like we shuffle **lists** so is there any method to shuffle.

Comment: `userDoc` is a `Future`.  Did you `await` it?  Exactly what did you try to shuffle it?  You say "[it's] not working", but exactly what happened?

Answer (score 0):

if you know how to shuffle data(posts in your case) via List, it wouldn't be a problem you can simply add posts to the List(or List of anything you want) and then shuffle them up.

Here's how you can add them to a list.

```
List<String> posts = [];
userDocs.documents.forEach(
  (post){
    posts.add(Post.fromFirestore(post));
  }
);
```

I'm assuming you do have a Factory function in your Post class, where you can convert data from dynamic to your desired structure.